# Keyword Text Recognition and Extraction

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I'm trying to build an architecture that recognizes words that are related to a subject word from a paragraph of text. These "related" words can be words that describes the subject word or provides information about the subject word.

Here's a basic example:

John is 36, male and lives in New York. He's a skinny, about 5'9 with fair skin.

In this example, the subject word would be, "John". 
The related words are "36", "male", "new york", "skinny", 5'9", "fair skin".

I already have a ruled based approach to identify the subject word which is working perfectly fine. Identifying the "related" words is not yielding the accuracy I'm hoping for. To identify the related words, I've taken supervised learning and LSTM structure approach. While I used a combination of PoS tags and dependency tags in the beginning, I have now switched to pure embeddings (transformer-based models).

Any architectural or method recommendations would be greatly appreciated.